# How can I change port for Camunda webapp (cockpit) on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, embedded-tomcat-8, spring-framework-beans

I want to change "camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp" port when I springframework application.
My project is running on 8181 "application.properties server.port = 8181"
and I did implement camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp on my build.gradle.
when I run my project camunda cockpit running on 8181 port.
I want to change when I start project runs on 8181 but camunda cockpit runs on different port.
How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? It is not supported out of the box and not really a specific camunda question. I found this link: https://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html and would be interested if this can be done.